# Create custom route in Custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, custom

How to create a custom route in Magento 2

http://127.0.0.1/magento8/trails/post/view/id/13

module:- trails

folder :-post

controller :- view

argument :-id/13

I want to http://127.0.0.1/magento8/slug/

[image]

anyone help me

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Only Custom module created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an entry in 
**Admin Panel > Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites**

with request path as **slug** and target path as **trails/post/view/id/13**

This should help.

Answer (score 3):

**You have to create a custom router.**

**First define custom router**

Create **di.xml** at `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/` and define the custom router

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="customrouter" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="class" xsi:type="string">{Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\CustomRouter</item>
                  <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
              </item>
          </argument>
      </arguments>
  </type>
</config>
```

**2. custom router point your slug to trails`/post/view/id/13`**

Use of custom router means to point a custom URL `http://example.com/index.php/mytesturl/` to Magento **own routing** `http://example.com/index.php/front_name/controller/action/` .
On custom router match  request path slug with

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CustomRouter implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Config primary
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $_appState;

    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url

     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validate and  modify request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);

        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();

        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->_response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect::class);
        }

        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }


    if (($condition->getContinue() == {slug}) {
         $request->setModuleName('trails')->setControllerName('post')->setActionName('view')->setParam('id', 13);
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class);
        }
    return null
    }
}
```

Comment: if (($condition->getContinue() == {slug}) {   undefine error  {slug}

Comment: You that {slug} with your slug

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento8/test1/   if (($condition->getContinue() == 'test1')) {       getting error  404  Whoops, our bad...

Comment: @AmitBera How magento will know that for this particular route it needs to use this router?

Comment: The code `if (($condition->getContinue() == {slug}) {
         $request->setModuleName('trails')->setControllerName('post')->setActionName('view')->setParam('id', 13);
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class);
        }`  As per as your business logic ,you have to map your router

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Create a new file in trails/post/etc/config.xml and copy following content :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
>     <router id="standard">
>         <route id="slug" frontName="slug">
>             <module name="trails_post" />
>         </route>
>     </router>
> </config>
> ```

2. Rename controller to Index

Comment: Please accept the answer also. If it works.

Comment: folder  structure my module