# How do I add an id/parameter to a frontend route?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, routing

I want to add an **"id"/"parameter"** to a front-end route in the following way:

```
store.example.com/blogpost/view/**213**
```

where 213 is the parameter I want to pass.

I have been looking at the [Magento 2 dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html), but I can't seem to find anything regarding adding this parameter.

And I can't seem to find anything that adds the "id" to the existing product route (`catalog/product/view/id/:id`) in magento/module-catalog. I'm probably missing something.

**etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="blogpost" frontName="blogpost">
            <module name="MyModule_BlogPost" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Controller/View/Index.php**

```php
<?php

namespace MyModule\BlogPost\Controller\Search;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // This only includes url query parameters ?param1=123&param2=active
        $params = $this->getRequest->getParams();

        // But I'd like to do this like the catalog/product/view/id/:id route ...
    }
}
```

Do I need to make a custom router for this, or is there another way?

Comment: Is that custom route you have created is for grid? does this controller gets triggered on button click?

Comment: It's for when I make a request to `store.example.com/blogpost/view/213` as a frontend page.

Comment: have you checked this url https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226602/create-custom-route-in-custom-module-magento-2

Comment: Yes, but that question is about making a "pretty" url for an existing route.